# query of records dated the next day, without Saturdays or Sundays

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I need to make a query in eloquent that brings me the records dated for the day after the current day. In other words, I need today, Friday 7/1, to load the records whose date entered in the variable $fechaip is equal to the following day. But, not taking into account Saturdays and Sundays. Is it possible to do something like this? To get the current date I suppose I can use Carbon... for example something like:

```
$today = Carbon\Carbon::now()
```

and then maybe use

```
$date = $today->addDay();
```

I think this would work, but how would I except Saturdays and Sundays?

Comment: I was able to solve this with the following code


$date = new Carbon('tomorrow');
        if( $date->dayOfWeek == Carbon::SATURDAY || $date->dayOfWeek == Carbon::SUNDAY || $date->dayOfWeek == Carbon::FRIDAY ){
        $date = $date->next('Monday');
        }

        $siguiente = $date->toDateString();

        $siniestros = Siniestro::where('estado', 'coordinado')->where('fechaip', $siguiente)->get();
        $users = User::all();

Answer (score 0):

```
// Starts on next day
$date= Carbon::tomorrow();
    
// Format N = 1 - for mondays, 7 - for sundays, here you can add conditions to ignore some days.
// If 6 or 7 (saturday or sunday), pass to the next day.
while (in_array($date->format('N'), [6, 7])) {
    // Next day
    $date->addDays(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = Carbon\CarbonImmutable::now(); // use immutable so $today is not modified
$date = $today->addWeekday();
```